# Applying a filter on each column of the dynamic table in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to create a general table using element type custom directive that takes collection of data and generates the table header and create all the rows and columns of the table, then i tried to sort all the columns. The part of this code is working fine. But my next goal is to apply the filter on all the columns of the table, as the data is dynamic so we cannot decide about the field to filter at run time. The problem I diagnosed is that I am using `ng-repeat="row in customers|filter:{$scope.searchkey:$scope.search}"`. Here seems to be the problem because in then expression the first thing should be object but $scope returns object.

Following is my code.

Index.html

```
<body>
<div> 
    <my-table input="Customers"></my-table>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <my-table input="Users"></my-table>
</div>
</body>
```

script.js

```
angular.module('DirectiveDemo', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      $scope.Customers = [{ Name: "2Touqeer", Code: "2" },
                              { Name: "3Nadeem", Code: "3" },
                               { Name: "1Talha", Code: "1" },
                               { Name: "4Muslim Khan", Code: "4" }

      ];
      $scope.Users = [{ Name: "Touqeer", Code: "2", ID: "2Touqeer", CID: "CID1" },
                            { Name: "Nadeem", Code: "3", ID: "3Muslim", CID: "CID3" },
                             { Name: "Talha", Code: "1", ID: "1Nadeem", CID: "CID2" },
                             { Name: "Muslim Khan", Code: "4", ID: "1Talha", CID: "CID5" },
      { Name: "Khan", Code: "4", ID: "1Khan", CID: "CID78" }
      ];

  }])
  .directive('myTable', function () {
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          transclude: true,
          scope: {
              customerInfo: '=input'
          },
          templateUrl: 'my-table-info.html',
          controller: function ($scope) {

              $scope.searchKey = 'CID';
              alert($scope.searchKey)
              $scope.reverseSort = false;
              $scope.search = '';
              $scope.List = [];
              $scope.order = function (item) {
                  $scope.orderByField = item;
                  alert($scope.search)
              }

              $scope.filterValue = function (itemKey,valueKey) {
                  $scope.searchKey = itemKey;
                  if (valueKey != 'undefined') {

                      $scope.search = valueKey;
                      alert($scope.search)
                  }


              }

          }
      };
  })
```

my-table-info.html

```
<table ng-transclude>

    <thead class="GridHeaderItem ControlBorder">
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="(key, value) in customerInfo[0]">  <a href="#" ng-click="order(key); reverseSort = !reverseSort">
                   {{key}}
            <span  ng-show="orderByField==key">
                            <span ng-show="!reverseSort">
                                <i class="glyphicon-circle-arrow-up glyphicon"></i>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="reverseSort">
                                <i class="glyphicon-circle-arrow-down glyphicon"></i>
                            </span></span>
                </a></th>
    </tr>
        <tr class="ControlBorderRight ControlBorderTop ControlBorderBottom">
         <td class=" ControlBorderLeft ControlBorderBottom" ng-repeat="(key, value) in customerInfo[0]" >
             <input type="text"  style="width:100%;" ng-model="searchfilter"   ng-change="filterValue(key,searchfilter);"  />
             <!--ng-change="filter(key);"-->

         </td>
    </tr>
          </thead>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in customerInfo|filter:{co[row]:2}|orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort" class="ControlBorderRight ControlBorderTop ControlBorderBottom   ">

        <td ng-repeat="col in row" class=" ControlBorderBottom ControlBorderLeft Control LabelControl">{{col}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should build a custom filter function `angular.module('myMod',[]).filter('myFilter',function(){ return function(input){...} })` then your repeat should look like this: `ng-repeat="row in customers | myFilter"` - the `row` object will be fed to the filter function as the `input` parameter.

Comment: I am new to Angularjs. I have tried so much like this as I am using custom directive so its creating confusion. Please if possible then make this code working. I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: When they say: `{{ expression | filter:argument1:argument2:... }}` they don't mean that `filter:` is part of it they want you to replace `filter:` with the name of the filter to use. i.e: `{{ row in collection | myFilterName:param1ToSendToFilter:param12ToSendToFilter }}`  if you do use `{{ expression | filter:someParam }}` this means something entirely different as `filter:` has its own special meaning.

Comment: It applies the filter on all rows and all columns but i need to apply the filter on all rows of one column. I think so that i didn't get your point. Please if you can do it or provide the solution on fiddle.

Comment: Just keep it mind this is a general table and we don't know about the collection thats why I am unable to decide what to do in filter function "myFilterName"